# How does a negative value turn positive by calling it negative in the console?

Tags: javascript

i used Math.abs but I fail and found this solution, I am following on eloquent javascript and how did negative value is turned to positive, here is the code:

```
function isEven(n) {
 if (n == 0) {
  return true;
 }
else if (n == 1) {
 return false;
}
else if (n < 0) {
console.log(-n);
return isEven(-n); // turn -3 to 3?
}
 else {
 return isEven(n - 2); 
 }
 }

 console.log(isEven(-3));
```

Comment: _"i used Math.abs but I fail"_ ? Where ? Why ?

Comment: thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález i get it so it is -(-3) thanks i console and it's positive

Comment: @Rayon I was failing taking care of negative values with recursion and found this solution,

Comment: Also: `function isEven(n) { return n % 2 == 0; }`

Comment: You should have a look at the modulo operator instead of recursing in your isEven function.

Comment: @casraf There are some more fun ways, e.g. `function isEven(x) {return Number.isInteger(x / 2);}`

Comment: @TOAOGG it has to be recursion, I am following a problem of eloquent javascript i am at recursion page.

Comment: It's how numbers work. -3 can be thought of as "I remove 3", so -(-3) can be thought of as "I remove my removal". So if you've previously removed 3 and then *remove that removal* you are in essence adding [back] 3 instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are a simpler test case:

```
> console.log( -(-3) );
3
```

This is not a JavaScript peculiarity, it's how maths work.

Answer (score 3):

Console has nothing to do with this.

Think back to your math class. `-n` is a shortened expression for `(-1) * n`. If you multiply two negative numbers, the result is a positive number - and since you're multiplying by negative 1 (where positive 1 is identity for multiplication), the result is the same number, but positive.

Since you're checking `if (n < 0)` before you multiply by `-1`, you'll always get a positive number.

However, this is almost definitely not what you want - the code you found seems to be an example of how to use recursion to solve common problems. In real-world Javascript, you'd want something more like this:

```
function isEven(x) 
{
  return (Math.abs(x) % 2) === 0;
}
```

Comment: I never thoght it is multiplying when it's called return isEven(-n);

Comment: I think Luaan just wanted to make it obvious to you how negation works theoretically. The processor which is executing the code might just flip the negative bit.

For information on the represenation of signed integers you could read into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: @GlendonPhilippBaculio The two expressions are equivalent mathematically - they do no necessarily have the same implementation on the CPU (though the compiler will likely compile both to the same instruction).

Answer (score 1):

> it has to be recursion

Lets break the mold! Using `-1` instead of `2`. Assuming an integer;

```
function isEven(x) {
    if (x === 0) return 1; // ended
    return -1 * (isEven(Math.abs(x) - 1) ? 1 : -1) === 1;
}
```

---

Other fun ways to test for even that don't need `2` or mod/remaineder

```
function isEven(x) {
    return Math.round(Math.sin(5 * x / Math.PI)) === 0;
}
```

An `O(log n)` recursion

```
function isEven(x, a) {
    if (!a) a = [true, false];
    if (a.length > x) return a[x];
    return isEven(x, a.concat(a));
}
```